# Keep getting error when building redis rpm

Tags: redis, rpm, jemalloc

When I try to build my rpm for redis-3.2.3 I get the following error even though the file is there:

```
cc: error: ../deps/jemalloc/lib/libjemalloc.a: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [redis-server] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/amenmojara/rpmbuild/BUILD/redis-3.2.3/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.hv3YDt (%build)


RPM build errors:
   Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.hv3YDt (%build)
```

Comment: Probably your working directory isn't what you expected.

Comment: Are those `deps` included in the `redis` tarball? `rpmbuild` extracts the sources given into a working directory and assumes *everything* you need is there.